# como puedo heredar los atributos de una clase con solo atibutos?

Tags: python, herencia

perdonen quisera alguien que me ayude en esta duda que tengo nose si se puede hacer esto

```
 class Lista:
     def __init__(self, name, lastName, age):
          self.name = name
          self.lastName = lastName
          self.age = age
 
 class setlist(Lista):
       def __init__(self):
            super().__init__(self, name, lastName, age)
       
       def showUp(self):
            print(self.name)
            print(self.lastName)
            print(self.age)

root = setlist()
root.showUp()
```

Comment: No se entiende la pregunta. Qué quieres decir con "si se puede hacer esto". ¿Lo has hecho? ¿Qué ha pasado? ¿Ha funcionado como esperabas? Y si no ¿qué era lo que esperabas? Tampoco está claro el título, deberías explicarlo mejor en el cuerpo de la pregunta.

Comment: Supongo que hiciste esa pregunta por que el código te está dando error. Cuando haces `super().<algo>` **no** es necesario pasar el argumento self, Python se lo pasa automaticamente.

Comment: Otro error en tu código: name, lastName y age no existen dentro del código que nos pasaste. Sin embargo, tratas de pasar esas variables en setList. Eso debería de generarte un NameError, que sucede cuando una variable no está en el ambito local (dentro de la función) ni en el no local (fuera de la función).

Comment: Por cierto, quité la etiqueta flask ya que tu pregunta no tiene relación con dicha etiqueta.